# Display custom post types if tags match company name

Tags: wordpress, post, tags, advanced-custom-fields

I currently have an events post type which is filtered by date. This also needs to be filtered by company. As an example, only Company A can view events for Company A, and Company B can see events for Company B, and so on. I am trying to match this by having a custom field for the name of the company in the user field and then match that user field to a post tag, so I will have a post tag called 'Company A', 'Company B' etc.

This is my code so far:

@php

```
      $company = get_field('company');
      if ( wp_get_current_user() instanceof WP_User ) {
                $company = wp_get_current_user()->company;
      }
      $today= date('Ymd');

      $args = array(
           'post_type'         => 'event',
           'posts_per_page'    => -1,
           'order'             => 'ASC',
           'meta_query'        => array(
                'relation'     => 'AND',
                array(
                     'key'     => 'event_date',
                     'value'   => $today,
                     'compare' => '>='
                ),
                array(
                     'key'     => 'company',
                     'value'   => $company,
                     'compare' => '=',
                ),
           )
           );
           $query = new WP_Query($args);while($query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
           @endphp
```

Comment: you can not compare post tag value in meta_query. Check this wp_query for the post tag https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters

Comment: yes I see that, how do you suggest I accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'         => 'event',
  'posts_per_page'    => -1,
  'order'             => 'ASC',
  'tag' => $company,
  'meta_query'        => array(
      'relation'     => 'AND',
      array(
        'key'     => 'event_date',
        'value'   => $today,
        'compare' => '>='
      )
  )
);
```

Comment: This doesn't show any posts, I tried playing around with the code but still nothing.

Comment: Can you please recommend another solution that I can try.